# xcodebuild archive command does not create dSYM files inside the .xcarchive when running through Github actions

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, github-actions, xcodebuild, dsym

I am using Github actions to automate the build/deploy process for a project, and so within my .yml file, I have a step that uses the `xcodebuild archive` command to generate a .xcarchive file. The .xcarchive file is successfully created, however the dSYMs folder within it is always empty.

This seems to only be happening when I am running it for a Debug configuration thru GA, but it's fine when I run the same command locally. Likewise, when I do it for a Release configuration it seems to be fine both thru GA and terminal/locally.

In the logs generated by the archive command, I noticed that the `GenerateDSYMFile` step is missing for the GA-triggered Debug build, but its there for all other cases.

This workflow is also being facilitated through a personal machine that we own, so not sure if that means anything.

I have gone through many other posts regarding this and have tried setting the following in our project (running Xcode 14.3) already but no luck:

- Debug Information Format: DWARF with dSYM File
- Generate Debug Symbols: YES
- Deployment Postprocessing: YES
- Strip Linked Product: NO
- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy: NO

The command that I have in place right now is pretty straightforward:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE} -scheme ${SCHEME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -archivePath ${ARCHIVE_PATH} -destination ${DESTINATION} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean archive
```

Comment: Are you sure about Debug Information Format: DWARF with dSYM File for your ${CONFIGURATION} ?